# find $\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}x_n$ ?.

Tags: sequences-and-series

For $\alpha\in(0,1)$, let $(x_{n})$ be a sequence such that

$$x_{n}=\begin{cases}
  0, \ n=0 \\
 1, \ n=1 \\
 \alpha x_{n-1}+(1-\alpha) x_{n-2},\ n\ge 2
\end{cases}$$

**Problem.** Find $\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}x_n$.

---

> For $n\ge2$ we have
>
> \begin{alignat}{3}
> x_2 &= \alpha +( 1-\alpha)\cdot 0   &&=\alpha\\
> x_3 &= \alpha x_2 +(1-\alpha)x_1  &&=\alpha^2 - \alpha +1 \\
> x_4 &= \alpha x_3 +(1-\alpha)x_2  &&=\alpha^{3}-2\alpha^2 +2\alpha\\
> \end{alignat}
>   $$\vdots$$
>   $$x_{n+1}=\alpha x_n + (1- \alpha) x_{n-1}$$
>
> But I don't know how to approach the limit.

Comment: @AlexD I almost rolled back your edit, but settled in the end to only fix the (critical) typo in the definition of the recurrence relation itself. Please be more considerate before making such massive edits in the future. The point of a good edit is to render OP's question more clear and more readable. It is *not* to completely rewrite the question as *you* would have asked it, instead.

Comment: @dxiv Thank you, I'll consider this before making an edit in the future. My apologies.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hint: $\;x_{n+1}\color{red}{-x_n} =\alpha x_n\color{red}{-x_n} + (1- \alpha) x_{n-1} \iff x_{n+1}-x_n =(\alpha-1)(x_n-x_{n-1})\,$, so $\,x_{n+1}-x_n\,$ is a geometric progression, and therefore $\,x_n\,$ is the sum of a geometric progression.

---

[ *EDIT* ]   Followup hint: $\;x_{n+1}-x_n =(\alpha-1)(x_n-x_{n-1})$ $=(\alpha-1)^2(x_{n-1}-x_{n-2})$ $=\ldots$ $=(\alpha-1)^n(x_1-x_{0})=(\alpha-1)^n\,$.

Then $\,x_n = (x_n-x_{n-1}) + \ldots+(x_1-x_0)+x_0=(\alpha-1)^{n-1}+(\alpha-1)^{n-2}+\ldots+1=\ldots\,$

Comment: that mean $lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}x_n = lim_ {n\rightarrow \infty}1+( α-1) + (α-1)^2 +.....+(α-1)^n =lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}\frac{1({1-(α-1)^n})}{1-(α-1)} =\frac{1}{2-\alpha}$.....Am i right ?  or  Am i wrong @dxiv   Pliz tell me

Comment: @Henry The limit came out right, but your $\,x_n\,$ was off-by-one, see my edit.

Comment: thanks  a lots@dxiv

Answer (score 1):

HINT: Prove that $x_n=\frac{(\alpha-1)^n-1}{\alpha-2}$ inductively

Comment: im not getting  how  did u get $x_n=\frac{(\alpha-1)^n-1}{\alpha-2}$

Comment: technically, u can compute the formula of a sequence using matrix. See this post https://comeoncodeon.wordpress.com/2011/05/08/recurrence-relation-and-matrix-exponentiation/